# Why are these buttons always unavailable

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, these buttons that have always been extremely useful and convenient, are now always disabled. Why?

[image]

(Center, Alignment, Send to Back and Send to Front etc buttons.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They work just fine.  The alignment and spacing toolbar buttons require you to select more than one control before they can do their job.  It is fairly obvious from your screenshot that you've only got a single control selected.  Hold down the Ctrl key and click the other controls that you want to align or space.  The last 2 buttons (Bring to Front/Send to Back) require having more than one control on your form.  Again, no evidence in your screenshot that you have more than the one.

Comment: I swear I am getting dumber with age. Thanks for the reminder.